# mail() function at PHP with weird chars

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, email

I'm using the php mail function, it works kinda fine, i really don't like to use this function but will have to do for this one.

So the problem is, the special european characters are being shown in a funny way on the email, i tried to set the codification to iso-8859-1 and the same is happening:

```
$to = $eemail;
$subject = $campos[4];
$message = $campos[5];
$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'iso-8859-1');
$from = $campos[1];
$headers = "From:".$from."\r\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
```

The rest is a basic mail form, sent through AJAX:

```
$(function() {  
  $(".submita").click(function() {        
      var nome = $('#nome').attr('value');
      var email = $('#email').attr('value');
      var telemovel = $('#telemovel').attr('value');
      var loja = $('#loja').attr('value');
      var assunto = $('#assunto').attr('value');
      var mensagem = $('#mensagem').attr('value');

      var dataString = 'nome='+ nome + '&email=' + email + '&telemovel=' + telemovel + '&loja=' + loja + '&assunto=' + assunto + '&mensagem=' + mensagem;
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxload/conemail.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $(".mensagem").fadeIn();
      }
      });
      return false;
  }); 
});
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: `codification` - love it. Great new word for encoding.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge in the english vocabulary.
Translate to Portuguese the word "codification" and "enconding" and all end up with the same portuguese word.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: no worries, I'm not having a go, it just amused me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chk this link from php.net

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
```

Hope this helps, this is the small content from this php.net page I gave url of

```
Sending messages with polish special characters:
<?php
function plmail($mail, $sub, $mes){
    $headers = "From: ExRobot <robot@example.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

    $mes=htmlspecialchars_decode($mes,ENT_QUOTES);//optional - I use encoding to POST data
    mail($mail, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($sub)."?=", $mes, $headers);
}
?>
Page must be in utf-8 encoding.
```

Comment: The upshot of this answer is `Try encoding it with UTF-8 instead`. Which, while rather clumsily put, is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

if your encoding  or "codification" is different across platforms (ie the message/email, form, web browser, etc) you will get weird results...

most of the time you will want to go with utf-8

edit, if you cant get away with using utf-8, but have control of the page that displays the message, you could set a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: enconding, codification, have the same meaning in Portuguese, i'm sorry. 
can't stick to uft-8, the results are as bad as for not using any encoding type.

Comment: its not a shot at your knowledge of english, thats the professional term for it, as far as documentation is concerned...

alternatively, you could set the webpage that is displaying the message to use iso-8859-1 in a meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

Comment: the contact.html page is enconded with that charset, the contact.php doesn't need enconding.